# Show $X=Y P-a.s \iff E\{|X-Y|\}=0$

Tags: probability-theory

**Problem:**
Let $X,Y:(\Omega, \mathscr{A}, \mathbb{P}) \mapsto (\mathbb{R},\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}))$ be two real random variables in $\mathscr{L}^1(\Omega, \mathscr{A},\mathbb{P}).$

Show that if
$$X=Y \: \text{P-a.s} \iff E\{|X-Y|\}=0$$

*Note:*
$\mathscr{A}$ is a sigma algebra, and $\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R})$ is the Borel set on the set of real numbers.

**Attempt:**

$"\Rightarrow"$

It's given that $X=Y \: \text{P-a.s}$, i then define $Z=X-Y \: \text{P-a.s}.$ The expectation of $Z$ exists since it's assumed that $X,Y \in \mathscr{L}^1.$ So the expectation of $Z$ is
$$E\{Z\}=0 \: \text{P-a.s}$$

I can now conclude that
$$E\{Z\}=E\{X-Y\}\stackrel{\text{P-a.s}}{=}0$$

(I can't seem to get the absolut value in play.)

$"\Leftarrow"$

It's now assumed that $E\{|X-Y|\}=0.$ (Again i don't know how to get the absolut value in play.)
$$0=E\{X-Y\}\stackrel{Linearity}{=}E\{X\}-E\{Y\} \: \text{P-a.s} \iff E\{X\}=E\{Y\} \: \text{P-a.s}$$
By how $Z$ was defined this follows $E\{Z\}=0 \: \text{P-a.s},$ which mean for the discrete case
$$P(X=Y)=P(Z=0)=1 \: \text{P-a.s}$$
Which is $X=Y \: \text{P-a.s}$

Am i on the right track or deep in the mud?

**Thoughts**
I figured that since it's assumed that $X=Y \text{P-a.s}$ then the absolute value will secure that the expectation isn't negative. But yet again, i can't see how this helps me further.

Comment: Recall that if a random variable is non negative and we have $E(X) = 0$ then $X = 0$ P a.s ,thus if $E(|X-Y| = 0) $ implies $|X-Y| = 0$ P a.s

Comment: For the first part, recall that |X| = 0 if and only if X = 0, thus X-Y = 0 implies |X-Y| = 0 and consequently E|X-Y| = 0

Comment: Appreciate it, @Franlezana. Just what i needed!

Answer (score 1):

It's been awhile since I've done this, but...

## only if

$X=Y \ \text{P-a.s.}$

$\iff X-Y=0 \ \text{P-a.s.}$

$\iff |X-Y|=0 \ \text{P-a.s.}$

Then $E[\cdot]$ both sides.

## if

It's a thing like integral of nonnegative integrand = 0 implies integrand is zero.

http://mathonline.wikidot.com/integrals-of-nonnegative-measurable-functions-that-equal-zer --> The proof here is much harder than I remember it... There's also this: [X nonnegative and integral equal to zero implies measure of positive part zero](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/769510/x-nonnegative-and-integral-equal-to-zero-implies-measure-of-positive-part-zero) and that [Prove that $ f = 0 $ almost everywhere on $ E $ iff $ \int_{E} f = 0 $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2737433/prove-that-f-0-almost-everywhere-on-e-iff-int-e-f-0)

Even for Riemann integrals:

https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Continuous_Non-Negative_Real_Function_with_Zero_Integral_is_Zero_Function