# Is it true $X = Y \text{P-a.s}?$

Tags: integration, probability-theory, measure-theory, expected-value

**Problem**
Let $X,Y:(\mathbb{R},\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}),P)\mapsto (\mathbb{R},\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R})),$ and $P = f\cdot m$ where $f: \mathbb{R} \mapsto \mathbb{R}, f(x)=1_{(0,1)}(x)$ is the uniform density. X and Y are two random variables defined by
$$X(x)=2x, Y(x)=2x\cdot 1_{(0,1)}(x)$$

Is it true $X = Y \text{P-a.s}?$

**Attempt:**
[From a previous question it's known that $X = Y \text{P-a.s} \iff E\{|X-Y|\}=0.$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4629169/show-x-y-p-a-s-iff-e-x-y-0)

So

$$E\{|X-Y|\}=E\{|2x-2x\cdot 1_{(0,1)}(x)|\}=\int 2x-2x\cdot 1_{(0,1)} f(x)dm(x)=$$
Since x is retricted to the interval $(0,1),$ then the indicator function in the integral equals 1 whichs gives:
$$\int (2x-2x\cdot 1_{(0,1)}) 1_{(0,1)}(x)dm(x)=\int_{(0,1)} 2x-2x\cdot 1_{(0,1)}dm(x)=\int_{(0,1)} 2x-2xdm(x)=\int_{(0,1)} 0dm(x)=0$$

Is this correct?

Comment: It is correct but the formula $\int 2x-2x\cdot 1_{(0,1)} 1_{(0,1)}(x)\,dm(x)$ needs parentheses since one could confuse it with $\int 2x-2x\cdot 1_{(0,1)} \,dm(x)$.

Comment: I actually just forgot. Thank you for noticing.

Comment: I don't think this is correct. 1 - You said 'Since x is retricted to the interval (0,1),
 then the indicator function in the integral equals 1 whichs gives:' and this is kinda the key step.  2 - how did you just drop the absolute value?